# Avoid inverted exclamation and question marks, when followed by quotes

Tags: punctuation

In an automated system that is generating LaTeX to render PostScript and PDF, i need to avoid an ambiguity in LaTeX:

- Two backticks (``` `` ```) produce a closing doublequote: `“`
- A question/exclamation mark followed by a backtick (`` ?` ``) produces the inverted character: `¿`
- Combined, when trying to display a question mark followed by a quote (``` ,,what?`` ```), LaTeX produces the following output: `„what¿‘`

What is the best practise to avoid this?
The desired output is: `„what?“`

Comment: Are you using this for German?

Comment: @egreg yes! does it make a difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the ligatures using `microtype`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[?,!]{encoding=T1}

\begin{document}
,,Hier?``

,,Hier!``
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or teach the automated system to use UTF-8 and input the “real” characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
„Hier?“

„Hier!“
\end{document}
```

As cgnieder suggests, there's another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
"`Hier?"'

"`Hier!"'
\end{document}
```

Comment: More possibilities: `babel` shortcuts ``"` `` and `"'` for the quotes or using `csquotes` :)

Answer (score 0):

I simply used curly braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
test?{``}
\end{document}
```

seems to work ;-)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.  Typeset [this example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a7750dc5a24d34306612a4b22369c6b7) with LuaLaTeX ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NmRTE.png)).

Comment: @HenriMenke with pdflatex I seem to get the desired `?“` (but perhaps with a larger than desired spacing after the `?`)